# What does "certainty" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> If you are a male, with 95% certainty,
>
> Your Maximum Natural Height in cm (inches) =
>   (F + M + FF + FM + MF + MM) / 6 * 1.08 + 8.8 cm (3.5 inches)
>
> If you are a male, with 99% certainty,
>
> Your Maximum Natural Height in cm (inches) =
>   (F + M + FF + FM + MF + MM) / 6 * 1.08 + 14 cm (5.5 inches)

What does "certainty" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[certainty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certainty) is defined as "the state of being completely confident or having no doubt about something".

If you say that something is a 99% certainty, it means that there is some small doubt about it: there is a one-percent chance that it is not true. It can effectively be regarded as a probability.

In this case there is a one percent chance that a man's height will exceed the figure given by this calcuation.